# 教えてください。Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, uikit

Xcode Version 15.0
Apple Swift version 5.9
macOS Sonoma 14.0

StortboardでUITextFieldに文字を入力中に以下のエラーが出ましたが、何が問題でしょうか？

Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.

Comment: UITextFieldに文字を入力しただけであり、numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) に該当するような数値は作成していません。

Answer (score -1):

google翻訳
Error: このアプリケーション、またはアプリケーションが使用するライブラリが無効な数値 (NaN、または非数値) を CoreGraphics API に渡したため、この値は無視されます。この問題を解決してください。

とおっしゃってますよ